# Deploy laravel and php to heroku

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

I have a php app in which one of the module is of laravel.
File structure is

```
-Web-eng
--Procfile
--composer.json
--public
----index.php
----library.php
--laravelproj
----example-app
------public 
------composer.json
------(other files)
```

Now I can deploy the public (pure php) separately when copied in other folder
But i could not deploy the web-eng folder, it says
"Forbidden you don't have permission to access this resource"

I am sure this is due to laravel project

1. Do I have to rename the public folder in example-app?
2. Do I have to make another Procfile inside laravel project? One is already in web-eng having code

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/
```

3. composer.json inside example-app has in its `script`

```
"post-install-cmd": [
     "php artisan clear-compiled",
     "chmod -R 777 public/"
 ]
```

Do I need to add it somewhere else?

4. Do I need to move larabelproj folder inside public folder of Web-eng??

I tried to explain my problem well, please let me know is it miss details and help me to get the app deployed.

Comment: Have you setup the environment variables on Heroku? More info about how to do that here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#using-the-heroku-dashboard

Comment: I did but no use.

Comment: Make sure all the require environment variables are set including app key.
Set APP_DEBUG to true in environment variables. Then see if you get any errors in browser.

Comment: i got this:This page isn’t workingprolaravel.herokuapp.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: I would suggest publishing just Laravel application in root, on Heroku. Once you get that working, then you try to adjust the Procfile file.

Comment: Also, try to ssh into Heroku and double check the setup. Might also help if you share the log from the log when deploying app.

Comment: Thank you so much i will try these suggestions. And can you clearify that do i have to publish just "laravelproject" or do i have to publish whole laravel and php projects with the Procfile referencing to the laravelproject??

Comment: First, try just deploy the laravelproject, in the root of the Heroku instance. Procfile would be required like shown in this guide: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-laravel#deploying-to-heroku